# duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_PodsDummy_Pods_packager

Tags: ios, cocoapods, duplicate-symbol

I encountered a very strange thing. I used the cocoapods-packager to generate two frameworks, each of which depends on an identical third-party library. When I run two frameworks into my project, there is absolutely no problem. However, when I use cocoapods to integrate these two frameworks, xcode always prompts "duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_

1. PodsDummy_Pods_packager

".It means Pods-packager-dummy.o is repeated.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: two framewoks pod files conflicting with one another. They have something in common between them.

Comment: Yes, I understand.I have dealt with common files between two frameworks. What I mean is that the above error message will appear whenever using cocoapods.

Comment: yes , It will appear in ur case.

Comment: So how do I solve this problem?

Comment: As u are saying u are not getting problem when u are integrating frameworks manually. Don in that way.

Comment: I will try other ways, thanks

Comment: Finally, I found the error was that the podspec file's third-party library's reference was misplaced.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the references of these two frameworks with 'subspec'. In the podspec file, I originally wrote 's.dependency' on top of 's.subspec', so when using cocoapods, an error occurs.

So, I wrote 's.dependency' in every 's.subspec' and the problem was solved.

Correct writing is like this：

```
  s.subspec 'XXXX' do |ss| 
    ss.vendored_frameworks = '**/XXXX.framework'
    ss.dependency 'xxx'
  end
```